# UILocalNotification sometimes don't notify me

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

in my app i schedule some UILocalNotification every time the app is opened, but happen that sometimes the uilocalnotification is not fired and don't notify me,and when happen they don't fired anymore, to fix it i have to reinstall the app on the iPhone, so i'm explain me well, there is a period of time that the notification work and then one day the dont' work anymore and to fix it i have to reinstall it again, so to investigate i have create this method that it's called when the app did become active:

```
-(void)checkNotification {

for (UILocalNotification *someNotification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {

    NSLog(@"%@",someNotification.alertBody);
    NSLog(@"%@",someNotification.fireDate);
}
}
```

and i see that all notification are scheduled and also the date, this is an example:

```
2012-11-25 18:36:36.532 TestApp[672:907] This is a notification.
2012-11-25 18:36:37.482 TestApp[672:907] 2012-11-27 10:00:00 +0000
```

so i can't understand why i don't receive notification...any help?

**Edit:**
i create a notification in this way:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = myNewDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = @"This is a notification.";
localNotification.soundName = @"smallBell.mp3";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: The verb form of notification is notify (not notificate) ;-)

Comment: sorry for the english i edit it now :)

Comment: How do you post the notifications? And how do you handle them?

Comment: i have edited my question, the problem is that the notifcation are scheduled, but happen that sometime they don't notify me...

Comment: If your app is running at the time of the notifications, no alert is displayed. Instead `UIApplicationDelegate`’s `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` method gets called. Could this be the problem?

Comment: yes i now that when the app is running no alert is displayed, but the app is not running when i wait for the notification alert...don't work...

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not get the alert message. It depends on whether your app is running and in which state, e.g. active in the foreground, active in the background, or not running at all.

Please see this article for clarification - http://www.thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/62-uilocalnotification-demystified.html

Comment: i can't understand this answer, the problem is that the notification are saved how i said in my question if i insert the nslog when i open the app i can see that the notification are saved in the system, i know that if the app is open, i can't see the notification but i can catch it with the specific method, the problem is that when the app is totally closed or in the background, the notification don't notify me, are saved but don't appear...

Comment: when your app is not running, iOS will alert the user visually. The user may choose to ignore it or take the action to launch your app, so you app will not necessarily get informed.